# Generate ints over a binomial distribution with a given mean

Tags: random, statistics

I'm writing code to create simulated behavior. As part of this, I know I want to simulate X events per minute. I don't want to just do x/60 events per second. Instead, I'd like to distribute these events across a binomial distribution that ends up averaging x/60.

These are events, so we're dealing with integers only. And the distribution doesn't have to be perfect of course. Just something more realistic than a consistent N-per-second-every-second-all-day-long.

Two questions:

1) Is there any pseudo-code or formulas that could help me calculate these datasets better than just my own tweaking in excel?

2) Are there any terms I'm mis-using (all of them probably) that could help me better find answers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're (probably) actually asking for a Poisson process (not binomial) -- the distribution
that arises when there is a uniform probability of an event happening per unit time.  This kind of distribution arises alot in queuing theory, so references there can help.

The easiest way to generate these is to generate the time-intervals between events:

```
generate_time_interval_in_seconds( X=mean_events_per_minute )
    dt=-(60.0/X)*log( random_number_generator() )
    return dt
```

`random_number_generator()` returns a pseudo-random number in `0-1`.  Taking `-log(.)` of it yields a random number which is exponentially distributed, with a mean value of `1`.
Scaling this by `60.0/X` gives us an exponentially distributed variate whose mean value
is the mean interval between events.

Then to determine how many occur in this minute do:

```
count=0
T=generate_time_interval_in_seconds(X)
while( T<60.0)
   ++count
   T+=generate_time_interval_in_seconds(X)
return count
```